# At a 2:40 rate — slang for high speed

Tags: slang, phrase-origin, nineteenth-century-english

I've run across the phrase "at a 2:40 rate" in mid-19th Century sources. The context suggests that it means "at high speed," but I'd like to know the derivation. If it means a mile in 2 minutes, 40 seconds, then that's 23 miles per hour, a very respectable speed for a light horse-drawn carriage. If it's a 4.5-furlong race track, then it's about 43 mph which is a great speed for a thoroughbred racehorse. Does anyone know for sure?

For example:

> This lady has never let an occasion slip on which she could abuse and villify the Southern Confederacy. A short time since she was on board a steamer, going up from New Orleans and was, as usual, wagging her tongue at a 2:40 rate against our section. — [The Daily Dispatch: July 29, 1861](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2006.05.0230%3Aarticle%3D7)

Comment: There seem to be *dozens* of written instances, in a fairly wide variety of contexts. For example, *The young shoots of strong growing varieties, when **growing at a 2:40 rate,** have a feeble hold on the old wood...*

Comment: chatgpt says it's to do with the rate of cutting down and replanting trees, but I dunno about that

Comment: two of the earliest examples on google books are "makes his " two forty " before a neighbor's sulky" (horses); and "who bet on horse races and the elections and loved fast driving and to talk about 'such a splendid rig' and their 'two forty' and all that" which might point to a distance. Is this a "Star Wars parsecs" thing? One is c 1855, the other 1860.

Comment: I also found ["at a forty rate"](https://books.google.com/books?id=UE8qAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA881&dq=%22forty+rate%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfz73khLKAAxXUFlkFHTJ4DFo4HhC7BXoECAMQBg#v=onepage&q=%22forty%20rate%22&f=false)

Comment: Sometimes given as "a two forty rate" or "a two-forty rate".

Comment: I'll note that, when I was a youngster, "a mile a minute" was a very common expression, translating into "60 miles an hour".  This was not an "amazing" speed, but quite fast for a "normal" person driving a "normal" car on a "normal" highway.  Someone running fast in a foot race, for instance, might be described as going "a mile a minute", eg, even though that was an exaggeration.  I didn't understand the jocular use of the term until I got into my teens.

Comment: @HotLicks There was also "going like sixty" in that era.

Comment: This is probably just a numerical coincidence, but I note the following entry in John Baddock, [_Slang: A Dictionary of the Turf, the Ring, the Chase, the Pit, of Bon-ton, and the Varieties of Life_](https://books.google.com/books?id=KKNWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%22Distance+(turf)%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK1qHi5rKAAxVIMDQIHUBFDXIQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Distance%20(turf)%22&f=false)  (1823):

Comment: "*Distance* (turf)— **two hundred and forty** yards is a *distance*, and horses which are thus far from the winning-post in one heat are not allowed to start again; such are set down as '*distanced*.' 'Double-*distanced*' is the same thing, superlatively—farther off; 'out of sight' expresses it as well." So in horse racing in the early decades of the nineteenth century, "240 [yards]" clearly had a special meaning tied to a disqualifyingly poor racing time—rather like getting skunked in cribbage.

Comment: Nice first question :) I see you've left comments under both answers indicating that they were helpful; you should consider accepting one of them by clicking the checkmark. (my vote is that you choose Tinfoil Hat's because it has an authoritative reference.)

Comment: The last verse of the song "Jingle Bells", from the 1850s, refers to a fast horse: "Just get a bobtailed bay / **Two forty** as his speed / Hitch him to an open sleigh / And crack! you'll take the lead."

Comment: That’s a great find, @MichaelLugo !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the *OED*:

> **two-forty** *noun*
> *U.S. colloquial.*
>
> An expression for a high speed (originally *spec.* at the rate of a
> mile in 2 min. 40 sec., formerly a ‘record’ pace for trotting).*
>
> <sub>1855   **I had introduced..a team of ‘two-forty’ reindeers.** M.
> M. Thompson, *Doesticks ii.* 20</sub>
>  <sub>1889   **Two-forty. To
> go at two forty, or at two forty pace, is to proceed at a high rate of
> speed. The allusion is to the record pace at trotting matches, at one
> time a mile in two minutes forty seconds being considered very good.**
> J. S. Farmer, *Americanisms*</sub>
>  <sub>1896  **Now, get a two
> forty move on you, nags!** G. Huntington in *Chicago Advance* 26 March
> 450/3</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=two-forty) (login
> required)</sub>

The [*Americanisms* entry for two-forty](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Americanisms_Old_New/OQY1AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22two-forty%22&pg=PA544&printsec=frontcover) (see 1889 example above) ends with the sentence: *Now the speed attained is much higher.*

The earliest print usage Google Books turns up is in 1844:

> *. . . and my father says I may go with him to the next trotting match. You know that bay colt father calls mine !—why I've
> got him so that he can trot a mile in two forty !*
> <sub>[*Temperance Dialogues, for Juvenile Meetings, Pic-nics, Fourth
> of July,
> &c*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Temperance_Dialogues_for_Juvenile_Meetin/o3JfAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22two-forty%22%20%22horse%22%20%22trot%22&pg=PA22&printsec=frontcover),
> American Temperance Union (pub), 1844</sub>

---

* <sub>Trotting refers to the pace of “trotters” — horses that are “bred to race at a fast trot instead of a gallop, while pulling a driver in a lightweight cart called a sulky.” [(American Museum of Natural History — *Bred For Speed*)](https://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/horse/how-we-shaped-horses-how-horses-shaped-us/sport/bred-for-speed)</sub>

[image: Currier & Ives illustration of horse Maud S. and driver]
<sub>The Queen of the Turf MAUD S., Driven by W.W. Bair By Harold, dam Miss Russell, by Pilor, Jr. Record 2:08 3/4, Currier & Ives, D'Amour Museum of Fine Arts, 1880 ([image from Springfield Museums](https://springfieldmuseums.org/collections/item/the-queen-of-the-turf-maud-s-driven-by-w-w-bair-by-harold-dam-miss-russell-by-pilor-jr-record-208-34-currier-ives/))</sub>

Comment: Thanks to Tinfoil Hat for the great response. The key is "trotters" -- thoroughbreds gallop at around 45 mph.  Cheers --

Answer (score 20):

Your interpretation is right: '2:40' does indeed refer to the amount of time it took the horse to go a mile. What's important is that these are not cart-pulling horses, these are *racehorses*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-forty) tells us:

> ***two-forty:***
> 1 : a speed of a mile in two minutes and forty seconds
> *ran like two-forty*
> 2 : high speed
>
> Etymology:
> so called from its having once been a trotting record

That trotting record appears to have been the record set by a popular horse named 'Top Gallant'. From *[Wallace's Monthly](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wallace_s_Monthly/HtRIAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=slang%20horse%20fast%20%222:40%22&pg=PA336&printsec=frontcover)*:

> Top Gallant (foaled about 1806) was perhaps the most popular horse of his day. He does not appear to have won much nor often, yet, like some politicians, he preserved his popularity for all of that, and **his time, 2:40** (although beaten the same year by the Treadwell mare)**, was the slang phrase for speed for twenty years later.**

A slightly different explanation is offered in the 1867 book *[Black and White](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Black_and_White/ZypLAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=slang%20horse%20fast%20%222:40%22&pg=PA158&printsec=frontcover)*:

> Two minutes and forty seconds is the least time in which a match horse is expected to do his mile, and a regular 2'40' is a slang phrase expressive of anything fast' all through the States.

Here, for instance, is the [1906 New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/1906/09/13/archives/sweet-marie-trots-to-new-worlds-record-in-fastest-mile-of-year.html) announcing the horse 'Sweet Marie' setting a new world-record mile for a mare:

[image]

It's clear from reading this that the '2:03¾' here is the amount of time it took for her to do the mile. It appears to have been a metric for measuring horse-speed; the 1900 *[Clark Horse Review](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Clark_s_Horse_Review/oKkQAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22at%20a%22%20%22rate%22)* is full of mentions of horses going at 2:10, 2:48, 2:90, etc.

Here's another example from *[The Breeder's Gazette](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Breeder_s_Gazette/3I05AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22at%20a%202%3A40%20rate%22&pg=PA426&printsec=frontcover&bksoutput=text)*:

> Honest Charley could trot his half mile in 1:20 or **at a 2:40 rate**, and won more than one race at county fairs.

And from 1848, in the newspaper *[Religious Telescope](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Religious_Telescope/XYNPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA29-PA26&printsec=frontcover&bksoutput=text)*

> Justin Huntly McCarthy's new book reminds one of a horse race at a county fair where the steeds are called back about a dozen times; but when he gets started he goes **at a 2:20 rate** with growing excitement and compelling interest until he rounds up under the wire.

---

But a second meaning seems to emerge in the mid-nineteenth century. Here is, from 1856, a sort of travelogue published in the *[New-York Dispatch](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030364/1856-09-21/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1770&index=6&rows=20&words=2+40+at+rate&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1963&proxtext=%22at+a+2%3A40+rate%22&y=0&x=0&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)*:

> Don't know what to do exactly, so go to sleep, and dream that the devil is dragging me along at 2:40 rate, and his imps are sticking pins in me.

And an 1862 letter, describing rapid snowfall:

> Don’t talk to us about “mild southern climates,” and the “sunny south!” The snow is six inches deep this morning, and falling at a 2:40 rate still.  We are to have a sleigh-ride this afternoon. The boys all have fires in their tents and are comfortable.

---

I assume that, as with the human mile-time, the mile-time for horses has slowly been whittled down; the 2:40 that was so impressive in Top Gallant's time was nothing to write about in the following decades. That would perhaps account for some of the discrepancies noted by Weather Vane in the comments below.

Comment: So is a 2/40 rate only *average* or *steady* and not fast? *Honest Charley could **trot** his half mile in 1:20 or at a 2:40 rate...* and you quoted race times that were quite a lot faster. Was the river boat not making good speed? And what about the Confederacy angle? The OP's link shows the remark was taken as an insult.

Comment: ... was "2:40" taken to mean **pedestrian**?

Comment: @WeatherVane - see edit. (I know I haven't addressed all of what you said)

Comment: The additions are good, especially the "the slang phrase for speed for twenty years".

Comment: Reminds me of "a mile a minute"

Comment: ... IMO the 'slang phrase' reference should be promoted to the top of the answer, which follows from there.

Comment: Trotters, including Sweet Marie, are harness racers — they pull carts.

Comment: As for that "whittlilng down" of the time. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trot#Types), the 2:03 time of 1906 had only dropped to 1:59 as of 2013.

Comment: 2:10, 2:40 and 2:48 all seem very reasonable, but 2:90 puzzles me… surely that would be 3:20!

Comment: Thanks to Heartspring for the thorough and enlightening answer. Great info.